# How to iterate through Dictionary<string, object> using c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, c#-4.0, foreach

I have one

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> demo = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

List<String> key1val= new List<string>();
key1val.Add("1");
key1val.Add("2");
key1val.Add("3");

List<String> key2val= new List<string>();
key2val.Add("4");
key2val.Add("5");

demo.Add("key1", key1val);
demo.Add("key2", key2val);

foreach (var item in demo)
{
    foreach(var it in item.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(it);
    }
}
```

I want to iterate though all keys like `key1,key2`.

if current item is `key1` then inside loop should take all values with respect to `key1` and iterate it into 2nd loop

```
loop
iterate though key1
iterate though [1,2,3] 

loop
iterate though key2
iterate though [4,5]
```

Comment: Could you rephrase your question somehow? What output would you expect? What do you mean by "iterate though key1"?

Comment: Can you show how `demo` is **actually** initialised.

Comment: You should include where you have a problem in your question. Also, it looks like you have a <string, object> dictionary but fill it with <string, string>

Comment: maybe you wana use `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<int>>` instead ... you cannot iterate `object`

Comment: you won't be able to `foreach` an `Object`(which is your value type), you need to change your Dictionary to be something like `Dictionary<string, List<int>> demo`

Comment: sorry for the confusion updated question with details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, use 2 nested loops.

The outer one iterating over the keys, the inner one over the values of the corresponding entry :

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> demo = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

List<String> key1val= new List<string>();
key1val.Add("1");
key1val.Add("2");
key1val.Add("3");

List<String> key2val= new List<string>();
key2val.Add("4");
key2val.Add("5");

demo.Add("key1", key1val);
demo.Add("key2", key2val);

foreach (var key in demo.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(key);
    foreach (var elem in demo[key])
    {
        Console.WriteLine(elem);
    }
}
```

This outputs

```
key1
1
2
3
key2
4
5
```

Answer (score 3):

Using LINQ `SelectMany` to accumilate values into a single list:

```
foreach (string value in demo.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value))
{
    Console.WriteLine(val);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var item in demo )
{
   WriteLine("loop");
   WriteLine($"iterate though {item.key}");
   WriteLine($"iterate though {item.Value}");
   WriteLine();
}
```

This should output exactly what you want
But, you could:

```
foreach (var item in demo )
{
   WriteLine("loop");
   WriteLine($"iterate though {item.key}");
   if (item.Value is IEnumerable<string> val) foreach(var v in val) WriteLine(v);
   WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var item in demo)
{
    Console.WriteLine("loop");
    Console.WriteLine($"iterate though {item.Key}");
    var valueAsString = $"[{String.Join(",", item.Value)}]";
    Console.WriteLine($"iterate though {valueAsString}");
}
```

Output:

```
loop
iterate though key1
iterate though [1,2,3]

loop
iterate though key2
iterate though [4,5]
```

You can test: https://dotnetfiddle.net/REqIdD

Answer (score 1):

*Linq* Solution includes `Concat` to combine `Key` and `Values` into a *single* collection and `SelectMany` to *flatten* them:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> demo = ...

var result = demo
  .SelectMany(pair => new string[] { pair.Key }.Concat(pair.Value));  

// Let's have a look
foreach (var item in result)
  Console.WriteLine(item);
```